# Can't change jquery object css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I am trying to change the css of two of an elements child elements using Backbone and jQuery.  My code is not working.  I think the problem is that there is a difference between a DOM element an and a jQuery object.

Here is my code:

```
App.Views.ExploreCard.user = App.Views.ExploreCard.Parent.extend({
  name: 'user',
  allowUntyped: true,
  classes: 'explore-person-box shadowed',
  onclick: function() {
    window.location.assign(this.data.profilePath);
  },
  postRender: function() {
    App.HCS.redrawHCS(this.$el);
  }
});
```

and

```
App.HCS = {
  redrawHCS: function(elements) {
    elements.each(function(index, value) {
      console.log(value);
      var hcs = $(value).find('.score');
      var border = $(value).find('.user-card-avatar-round');
      var score = $(hcs).html();
      console.log(hcs);
      console.log(border);
      console.log(score);
      if ( score <= 33 && score >= 1 ) {
        $(hcs).css("background-image", "image-url('heart_primary.png')");
        $(border).css("border", "3px solid #ff4013;");
      }
      else if ( score <= 66 && score >= 34 ) {
        $(hcs).css("background-image", "image-url('body_primary.png')");
        $(border).css("border", "3px solid #008cb4;");
      }
       else if ( score <= 99 && score >= 67 ) {
        $(hcs).css("background-image", "image-url('minf_primary.png')");
        $(border).css("border", "3px solid #fb9f00;");
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I am not trying to do anything very difficult.  Just change some css rules.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are your `.score` and `.user-card-avatar-round` divs, inputs or what?

Comment: What do those three `console.log()` statements before the `if` show? (Also, not the problem, but you can say `hcs.css(...)` and `border.css(...)` - no need to wrap the variables in `$()` because `hcs` and `border` are already jQuery objects.)

Comment: `score` seems to be a string, but you are comparing it to numbers. Maybe you should explicitly convert it?

Comment: Prepending a dollar sign ($) to the name of query objects is a good practice: var $hcs = $(value)

Comment: Edgar Villegas Alvarado - they are both divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a `;` at the end of css values

```
$(border).css("border", "3px solid #fb9f00");
```

also for the image you need to use `url()` not `image-url()`

```
$(hcs).css("background-image", "url('minf_primary.png')");
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bg5bQ/1/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bg5bQ/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the changing of the `background-image` property should be:

```
$(hcs).css("background-image", "url('heart_primary.png')");
```

and not:

```
$(hcs).css("background-image", "image-url('heart_primary.png')");
```